# PHP MySql Swap value in two rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I've seen a couple variations on this, but mainly they swap the entire row rather than just one value in that row, and not dynamically.

Here's the issue:

I have three rows each with the following cells (id, title, content, display_order, visible).
id is auto_increment. title and content are manually entered and visible is a toggle.  display_order is set when each row is created and automatically set as the highest integer and set at the bottom of the stack.

I set it like this so that if any of these records were to be manually deleted, i can reorder the stack automatically (if there are 4 records, and I delete #2, the new order resets as 1,2,3 and not 1,3,4).

Each row has a set of up and down arrow buttons that call move.php with queries of id(id), display_order(pos) and direction(dir).

In the move.php it uses a conditional to determine whether to move the record UP or DOWN depending on what the direction variable is set at.

What PHP code do I need to write to take these three variables (id, pos, dir) and swap the value in the table cell display_order:  Here's a visual representation

Initial:

```
id   title   pos   
-----------------
 1   slide1   1
 2   slide2   2
 3   slide3   3
```

After I click the UP button for record ID #3:

```
id   title   pos   
-----------------
 1   slide1   1
 2   slide2   3
 3   slide3   2
```

MIND YOU the ID and POS will not always be the same integer

USING davidethell's suggestion I have created this:

Here's what I have created, but all I'm getting is the echo $newPos rather that is going back to the admin.php:

```
require ("connection.php");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $pos = $_GET['pos'];
    $dir = $_GET['dir'];

    if ($dir == 'up') {
        $newPos = $pos-1;
    } else {
        $newPos = $pos+1;
    }

    $fromRow = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$pos."";
    $toRow = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$newPos."";

    $reord = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE pages SET display_order = " . $toRow['display_order'] . " WHERE id = " . $fromRow['id']."; UPDATE pages SET display_order = " . $fromRow['display_order'] . " WHERE id = " . $toRow['id']);

    if ($reord){
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }else{
        echo $newPos;
    }
```

The problem I'm running into is that it only echos the $newPos

UPDATED CODE:

```
require ("connection.php");

    $fromArray = array();
    $toArray = array();

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $pos = $_GET['pos'];
    $dir = $_GET['dir'];

    if ($dir == 'up') {
        $newPos = $pos-1;
    } else {
        $newPos = $pos+1;
    }

    $fromRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$pos."");

    $toRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$newPos."");


    $reord = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE pages SET display_order = " . $toRow['display_order'] . " WHERE id = " . $fromRow['id']);
    $reord = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE pages SET display_order = " . $fromRow['display_order'] . " WHERE id = " . $toRow['id']);

    if ($reord){
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }else{
        echo $newPos;
    }
```

Result: echos the $newPos instead of return to admin.php

Comment: is the ID given, or is the position given? my answer assumes it's the ID, if it is the position you can just use `UPDATE pages SET display_order=CASE WHEN display_order=$pos THEN $newPos ELSE $pos END WHERE display_order IN ($pos, $newPos)` but it's better to use mysqli and it's also better to check if we are at the beginning or at the end of the table

Comment: @fthiella the up and down buttons are anchors with hrefs of move.php?id=XXX&posXXX&dirXXX.  move.php is the page with this script. id is the row ID in the database table. pos is the variable assigned to the table row's display_order and dir is if you clicked the UP or DOWN arrow.  So an example of you clicked the UP button on the 2nd row that has an ID of 54 would be move.php?id=54&pos=2&dir=up.  All three are captured in the $_GET commands at the beginning of the script.

Comment: i think you don't need to get both the id and the pos, you just need one of those (given the id you can calculate the pos, and viceversa), on my last code i assume only the pos is given because it's a little easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(yourtable.pos) pos_prec,
      curr.pos pos_curr
    FROM
      yourtable INNER JOIN
      (SELECT pos FROM yourtable WHERE id=3) curr
      ON yourtable.pos<curr.pos
    GROUP BY
      curr.pos) cp ON yourtable.pos IN (cp.pos_prec, cp.pos_curr)
SET
  pos = CASE WHEN pos=cp.pos_curr
             THEN pos_prec ELSE pos_curr END
```

It's a little bit complicated, but it will swap the value of the position where ID=3 with the value of the position of the preceding item, even if there are gaps.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ce01/1).

**EDIT**

If there are no gaps, you could simply use this to move ID#3 UP:

```
UPDATE
  yourtable INNER JOIN (SELECT pos FROM yourtable WHERE id=3) curr
  ON yourtable.pos IN (curr.pos, curr.pos-1)
SET
  yourtable.pos = CASE WHEN yourtable.pos=curr.pos
                       THEN curr.pos-1 ELSE curr.pos END;
```

and just use +1 instead of -1 to move down (both UP and DOWN can be combined in one single query if needed).

**PHP Code**

And this is using PHP and mysqli, and assuming that the position is given:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "test");

$pos = 3;
$dir = 'down';

if ($dir == 'up') { $newPos = $pos-1; } else { $newPos = $pos+1; }

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
  UPDATE
    yourtable
  SET
    pos = CASE WHEN yourtable.pos=?
               THEN ?
               ELSE ? END
  WHERE
    pos IN (?, ?)
    AND (SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE pos IN (?,?)) s )=2;"))
{

    $stmt->bind_param("iiiiiii", $pos, $newPos, $pos, $pos, $newPos, $pos, $newPos); 
    $stmt->execute();
    printf("%d Row affected.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

(i also added a check, if trying to move UP the first pos, or DOWN the last one it will do nothing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Although, I already am running a script that doesn't even render an UP arrow for the first record or a DOWN arrow for the last record.   What is the "iiiiiii" for?

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY... I just replaced the printf command with my header command.

Comment: @Murphy1976 thanks :) my query has some placeholders ?, with bing_param i'm binding every parameter to its placeholder, and the string iiiiii indicates the type of each parameter (i=integer), this is safer and can avoid sql-injections

Comment: This is only for a local application, I need not worry about SQL Injection.

Comment: Great answer, especially handling everything in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a $row object with each row data, just do:

```
if ($dir == 'up') {
    $fromRow = $row2;
    $toRow = $row1;
}
else {
    $fromRow = $row1;
    $toRow = $row2;
}
$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET pos = " . $toRow['pos'] . " WHERE id = " . $fromRow['id'];
// now execute your SQL however you want in your framework
$sql = "UPDATE mytable SET pos = " . $fromRow['pos'] . " WHERE id = " . $toRow['id'];
// now execute your SQL however you want in your framework
```

Put that in a function or class of some kind to make it reusable.

EDIT:
Based on your edits it looks like you are not fetching enough information in your queries. They should be:

```
$fromRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$pos."");

$toRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$newPos."");
```

You were only selecting the id field, but then you were trying to use the display_order field.

Comment: Here's what I have created, but all I'm getting is the echo $newPos rather that is going back to the admin.php:

Comment: Ok, you're getting an error in your MySQL call. What is the output of mysqli_error?

Comment: Your error is that you're trying to run two UPDATE statements in the same query call. Either split them into two calls or use mysqli_multi_query.

Comment: I removed the mysqli_query($conn, sections of the $fromRow and $toRow for each line reads: `$fromRow = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$pos."";
 $toRow = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE display_order = ".$newPos."";` I have updated the second portion of code to reflect this. Instead of the page returning to admin.php, the echo $newPos is displaying.

Comment: I can see that when I echo each of the $fromRow and $toRow, they are simply returning the query and not the value of the query.

Answer (score 0):

i will not write you the PHP code. But i will give you the SQL:

Let's say $delta is either +1 if the slide's position should be raised 1, or -1 if the slide's position should be lowered by 1.
$id is the id of the slide. Ow, and let's assume the table is called slides_table.

You will need 2 queries:

```
update slides_table set pos = pos + $delta where id = $id;
update slides_table set pos = pos - $delta where pos = (select pos from slides_table where id=$id) and id != $id
```